What's a realistic cadence for refueling an HLS Starship on-orbit?
In the wake of the IFT-5 booster catch, I've started to wonder what a realistic timeframe for refueling a lunar starship is.  From T-0 of a lunar starship launch to fully fueled for an Artemis mission, how much time will elapse?
It seems like there are a few potential long-poles to slow things down:

the rate of Starbase and/or KSC to take delivery of liquid oxygen and liquid methane.
the number of pads available (2 at Starbase, 1 or 2 at KSC?)
launch opportunities for minimizing rendezvous cross-track/plane changes

I don't think I've seen a lunar Starship HLS concept-of-operations (CONOPS) that includes a timeframe, just the infamous numbers of launches.

The primary long-pole items are, in my estimation, human/regulatory connected. Doubling the number of fuel delivery trucks can double the rate at which fuel gets delivered, while doubling the number of personnel working in the launch control center doesn't result in them being able to launch twice as frequently.

@Dragongeek which regulatory items are you thinking of?

For Apollo and Gemini (also) they appear to have worked with one or two orbit periods either side of the ideal target orbit, making for four hour windows, two hours either side of the ideal time, with one window per day. If heading to the moon there is also one window a month for LEO departure.
Assuming similar cross range performance margins this would mean that each day each site has three possibly four opportunities to launch, with a 90 to 120 minutes between opportunities within the window. For two towers at Starbase and two at KSC, that might work out to:

Launch tower one at first opportunity in the window

Launch tower two next time around

Hope you can turn around the tower one in 3-4 hours before the
window closes


For 6 launches per day across both sites, you can get higher numbers by doing multiple launches per site per pass, but that would seem ambitious at the moment. That gets 18 tankers in three days, probably enough to fill one Starship for a moon departure but multiple per monthly window might be a problem without more ground infrastructure.
A lot hinges on if you can truly catch a returning Super Heavy, stack a new Starship on it and start fueling in that window, or if you need some sort of revolving loader arrangement to hold stacked stages and returned boosters until window closes and humans can come into the tower area to service tower and stage equipment.

I believe the general consensus is that there will be a depot that is filled first, and the HLS Starship will then be filled from this depot. This would decouple the "get propellant to orbit" timeline from the "launch HLS and refill it" timeline. It would also mean that the risk of multiple dockings and propellant transfers is shifted from the "few-of-a-kind" HLS variant to the "dime-a-dozen" standard variant (or a yet-to-be-developed tanker variant).
